# How can I retrieve the AbortCount of a MSMQ message?

Tags: msmq

I'm retrieving messages from a MSMQ in a transaction. If the application cannot process them for whatever reason, then it aborts the transaction.

Once the transaction is aborted the message goes back into the queue. If the message is retrieved again, is there a way to know if the message was previously aborted?

Through the MMC (MSMQ UI), you can view the properties of the message to see how many times the message was aborted.

Is there a way to get this value programmatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the MSDN site:

> To keep track of the number of times a
>   message read is attempted, Windows
>   Vista maintains a durable message
>   property that counts the number of
>   aborts and a move count property that
>   counts the number of times the message
>   moves between the application queue
>   and subqueues. The WCF channel uses
>   these to compute the receive retry
>   count and the retry cycles count. On
>   Windows Server 2003 and Windows XP,
>   the abort count is maintained in
>   memory by the WCF channel and is reset
>   if the application fails. Also, the
>   WCF channel can hold the abort counts
>   for up to 256 messages in memory at
>   any time. If a 257th message is read,
>   then the oldest message's abort count
>   is reset.
>
> The abort count and move count
>   properties are available to the
>   service operation through the
>   operation context. The following code
>   example shows how to access them.

The page with the examples is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms789028.aspx).

Comment: This is obtained via WCF. Is there a way to get the AbortCount when not using WCF?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of.  The conventional wisdom when not using WCF is to increment a user-defined field with the abort count in the message and re-queue it.  If you just roll it back you cannot change it.  You can however put the updated message and the original message in the same unit of work so you do not risk losing messages.